# Why is this Javascript array-access so slow?

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js

I have a 5000-element array  (`frames_to_boxes`). Each element itself is an array of Objects of class Box:

```
class Box {
  constructor(x, y, width, height, frame, object_class, id) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.frame = frame;
    this.object_class = object_class;
    this.id = id;
  }
```

`frames_to_boxes` is indexed by frame. The purpose of `frames_to_boxes` is to use it to look up Boxes by frame-number rather than scanning through my yuuuge array of Boxes and checking for frame-equality.
However, I'm not getting the performance I expected; checking whether a particular element of `frames_to_boxes` is null is taking about 25ms according to my performance profiling. This seems wrong to me.
Here's how I'm profiling:

```
const t11 = performance.now();
if(this.frames_to_boxes[i] != null)
{
  const t12 = performance.now();
```

In my console logs, I print out the difference `(t12-t11)` and it's showing from 5ms to 25ms. The array is accessed in groups of 3 (i.e., check index 500, 501, 502) and it seems that the first access is usually around 25ms while the following two accesses are around 5ms.
If it makes a difference, `this.frames_to_boxes` is a Vue computed value; however, from my performance traces and logging, I have confirmed that the code to update `frames_to_boxes` is not being re-executed. It seems that the array-lookup is responsible for the timing.

Is 5-25ms unusual for this type of operation? If not, what might be responsible for my slow performance? My performance numbers are from Chrome.

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

For this type of operations I would rather use caching and
hash tables: javascript Objects.
then operation would take O(1) to check if it's null
or take the array of objects.

```js
const myNewHashTable = {
  box1: [1,2,3],
  box2: [1,2,3],
  box3: '', 
  box4: []
}


if (myNewHashTable['box1']){
  console.log('found', myNewHashTable['box1'])
}
if (myNewHashTable['box3']){
  console.log('found',myNewHashTable['box3']) //not printing
}
if (myNewHashTable['box4'].length > 0 ){
  console.log('found ','box4') //not printing
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it turns out that I was wrong about this being unrelated to Vue though, so I think the question of hash-tables vs. arrays was not the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create a minimal reproducible example without using Vue and the problem disappeared. This gave me the hint that although `frames_to_boxes` is not being recalculated, it appears that the Vue engine is checking for changed dependencies or something like that.

Applying `Object.freeze` on my Box elements before inserting them into the main array fixed the issue, and checking for null now takes less than 1ms as expected.